# $‎‎\sigma(x)‎$ ‎‎‎‎is ‎contained ‎in ‎the ‎imaginary ‎axis ‎of ‎the ‎complex ‎plane

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

$‎A$ ‎is a‎ ‎C*-algebra ‎and ‎‎$‎x‎\in A‎$ ‎satisfies ‎‎$‎x‎^*=-x‎$.‎I want to show that ‎‎$‎‎\sigma(x)‎$ ‎‎‎‎is ‎contained ‎in ‎the ‎imaginary ‎axis ‎of ‎the ‎complex ‎plane.How i prove it?

Comment: This is not a question, but a statement.

Comment: I don't think we should be so quick to downvote and chastise. According the the asker's profile, the asker lives in Iran. Perhaps their command of the English language and question-asking etiquette is not as great as we would like, but we should strive to interpret the question as generously as possible.

Comment: (To be totally clear, I don't mean to disparage Iranians. I only meant that we should be aware that people who live in countries where English is not common may not have a perfect grasp of it, and that we should be cognizant of that and try to accommodate as much as reasonably possible.)

Comment: I don't think we should assume that downvotes resulted from lack of English language mastery (mine didn't), or that there has been any chastisement here (I don't see any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a proof: $ix$ is self-adjoint by your assumption $x^* = -x$. So $\sigma(ix) = i\cdot \sigma(x)$ lies on the real line.